# Custom animation of fragment transaction disappears when hide keyboard

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-softkeyboard

I've an app for tablet with 4 Fragments (MyNavigationBarMaster, MyNavigationBarDetails, Master e Details).

I'use the Fragment transaction and custom animation (iphon-style) as follows:

```
FragmentTransaction mfragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
mfragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_out_right, R.anim.slide_in_right);
mfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.MenuMFragment, new PeopleMFragment());
mfragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

no problem for this but when i try to hide keyboard programmatically with this code in PeopleMFragment():

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

the animation of fragment transaction not working but the keyboard is hidden and the fragment is attached correctly.

why? the problem is to have a single thread for keyboard and xml animation?
someone else with the same problem? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with way. (I tried on htc desire)

```
public void nextFragment(){

    //close keyboard
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

    //remove focus, to remove any "auto-suggestions" views from the text field
    getActivity().getCurrentFocus().clearFocus();

    //change fragment
    Fragment2 newFragment = new Fragment2();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_left, R.animator.slide_out_right);
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, newFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();

}//nextFragment
```